ENVI Random Forest ROI file causing crash
I am trying to run the ENVI Random Forest Classification tool. I know there are better ways to set up a Random Forest classifier, but as this is the software provided for the course I am doing, I need to work with ENVI.
I have created my training data for a quite large high resolution image using the ROI tool, but I need to split it into training and validation data. To do this I export the ROI pixels as a multipart point shapefile, open the file in ArcGIS, run 'multipart to singlepart' to separate the pixels into individual points, then run the 'Subset Features' to create randomised 80/20 split training/testing datasets. I can then open the training shapefile in ENVI, run the 'Vector to ROI' tool and I have training ROIs.
The problem arrives when I try and use those ROIs in the Random Forest Classification tool. Attempting to run the tool with these ROIs renders ENVI 'unresponsive' every time. I have tried to wait it out for long periods to no avail.The only option at this point is to "end task" and reopen ENVI. If I run the classification using the original ROIs, before they were split, the tool runs fine. But with no validation that is pretty useless.
Does anyone know what is causing this? What part of my process for separating training/testing data is causing the issue? Any suggestions on a better workflow that will allow the tool to work?
